# Reading a sheet with a list of values, pull it into another calculator sheet, then copy the calculated value back to first sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I want to convert Degree C (with pressure compensation) into PPMv.

I have two sheets. The first sheet is the one with the raw data. I have another calculator sheet (which I got it from the internet) which is to convert Degree C to PPMv. I want to copy 2 types of data (Degree C & Pressure) to the calculator and then copy the calculated value back to the first sheet.

Code:

```
Sub CaculatePPM()
    Dim DewPoint As Double
    Dim Temp As Double
    Dim PPMv As Double
    Dim Iteration As Integer

    Iteration = 0
    Sheets("DewPoint").Select

    Do Until Selection.Offset(Iteration, 0).Value = ""
        Range("D7").Select
        Selection.Offset(Iteration, 0).Select
        DewPoint = Selection.Value
        Range("F7").Select
        Selection.Offset(Iteration, 0).Select
        Temp = Selection.Value

        Sheets("Calculator").Select
        Range("D14").Select
        Selection.Value = DewPoint
        Range("D16").Select
        Selection.Value = Temp
        Range("B19").Select
        PPMv = Selection.Value

        Sheets("DewPoint").Select
        Range("G7").Select
        Selection.Offset(Iteration, 0).Select
        Selection.Value = PPMv

        Iteration = Iteration - 1

    Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a better version of your code:

```
Sub CaculatePPM()
    Dim Iteration As Integer

    'Set iteration to the first row to be processed    
    Iteration = 7

    'Loop while there is data to be processed
    Do Until Sheets("DewPoint").Cells(Iteration, "D").Value = ""
        'Copy data to Calculator sheet
        Sheets("Calculator").Range("D14").Value = Sheets("DewPoint").Cells(Iteration, "D").Value
        Sheets("Calculator").Range("D16").Value = Sheets("DewPoint").Cells(Iteration, "F").Value

        'This next statement is probably not necessary, but I have included
        'it just in case Excel is set to Manual Calculation
        Sheets("Calculator").Calculate

        'Copy results back to DewPoint sheet
        Sheets("DewPoint").Cells(Iteration, "G").Value = Sheets("Calculator").Range("B19").Value

        'This originally said "Iteration = Iteration - 1"
        'Change it back if you are trying to process rows starting from 7 and working UPWARDS
        Iteration = Iteration + 1
    Loop

End Sub
```